# Replace pattern with RegEx in sed substitution

Tags: regex, unix, sed, pattern-matching

I am new to UNIX and I am using the `sed` command to substitute a pattern in my files.

The file content is:

```
xyx.filename are in Filename

filename are in Filename and app.filename is in Filename
```

I want to **ignore** the string "**.filename**" (i.e the string filename starting with a ".") and **substitute** the rest of the **filename** string (ie filename,Filename..etc) to **newname**

What regex will be used in the sed command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this :

```
$ sed -r 's/(^|[^.])filename/\1newname/gi' file
xyx.filename are in newname
newname are in newname and app.filename is in newname
```

#### Explanation

- `-r` is used to catch the groups with just `( ... )` instead of `\( ... \)`.
- `(^|[^.])filename` matches anything like `filename` in the beginning of the file or `filename` with any character in front that is not the dot `.`.
- `\1newname` it replaces it with `newname` together with the catched value (the one in front of `filename`).
- `gi` performs the replacement `g`lobally and `i`gnoring the case.

Comment: hey @fedorqui : can u suggest me how can i retive XYZ from XYZ.ABC in sed command. I tried a lot.!..Thanks!

Comment: @ajitbalachandran it is a bit broad, but the basic way would be `echo "XYZ.ABC" | sed 's/\..*$//'`. In case it happens to be a more general problem, do not hesitate to  [Ask a new uestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).